# Why Jmeter can't record sites using the firebase as data connection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, jmeter, load-testing

I tried to record a site using JMeter which uses Firebase for data storage but it fails to access the firebase and I can not log into the site while recording. Is there any way to access firebase during the recording of load testing in JMeter? I entered the JMeter certificate also but still, the problem is there. And also tried  using the chrome extension still it also didn't give the expected output [Error Description Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KZVq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's due to incorrect JMeter configuration for recording, you need to import JMeter's certificate into your browser. The file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`, JMeter generates it under its "bin" folder when you start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

See **HTTPS recording and certificates** documentation chapter for more details.

Going forward consider looking at [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener output and [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file, they should provide sufficient amount of information in order to get to the bottom of the issue. If you cannot interpret what you see there yourself - add at least essential parts of response/log to your question.

Also be aware of alternative "non-invasive" way of recording a JMeter test - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in that case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates and should be able to normally record whatever HTTP(S) traffic your browser generates